# Acceder a controles creados en tiempo de ejecución con Java

Tags: java, javafx

Quiero crear muchos controles `Label` dentro de un contenedor en tiempo de ejecución. ¿Es posible acceder a estos controles `Label` más tarde mediante un nombre para cambiarles la apariencia sin tener que hacer un bucle por el contenedor mirando su contenido?

Algo que pueda parecerse a este código (aunque es incorrecto, claro):

```
FlowPane panel = new FlowPane();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   panel.getChildren().add(new Label("etiqueta"+i));
}

etiqueta1.setText("texto");
etiqueta2.setText("texto"); 
etiqueta3.setText("texto");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una solución implementada con la que no necesitas crear un mapa, mediante el método `lookup` sobre el método `setId` de los elementos de javaFx

```
public class Controlador{

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Aquí tu códgio que genera el panel

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            String key = "etiqueta"+i;
            Label label = new Label();

            // Se establece el identificador
            label.setId(key);
            panel.getChildren().add(label);
        }
    }

    // Obtención del elemento
    panel.lookup("#etiqueta1").setText("texto");
    panel.lookup("#etiqueta2").setText("texto");
    panel.lookup("#etiqueta3").setText("texto");
}
```

El método **setId** extraído de la [documentación de oracle:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution)

> Establece un fx:id a un elemento creando una variable en la tabla de
>   espacios de nombre que puede ser recogida de forma posterior...

El método **lookup(String)** extraído de la [documentación de oracle:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)

> Una función llamada lookup puede ser utilizada para para encontrar un
>   nodo con id único a partir de la escena, o de cualquier subelemento de
>   la escena. Además, el id puede...

Comment: No conocía esa función, aunque para ser sincero no he llegado a tocar mucho de javaFx. Dejo de todas formas mi respuesta por si le sirve a alguien que no utilice javaFx

Comment: Claro, yo intenté ajustarme a la etiqueta de la pregunta la verdad

Answer (score 5):

Podrías usar un Mapa de tipo (String, Label) y almacenar ahí los labels creados. Cuando quieras recuperar uno de ellos, simplemente tendrías que hacer map.Get("etiqueta1") para obtener ese label.

Creo recordar que sería algo así:

```
FlowPane panel = new FlowPane();
Map<String, Label> mapa = new HashMap<String, Label>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String nombre = "etiqueta" + i;
    Label label = new Label(nombre);
    mapa.put(nombre, label);
}

mapa.get("etiqueta1").setText("texto");
mapa.get("etiqueta2").setText("texto");
mapa.get("etiqueta3").setText("texto");
```